# Send to back functionality in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I'm having the following use case that I want to achieve in HTML

`I've two div element with background red and blue. The blue div is added later of which a part overlaped with red div.
I have the option of "send to back" which sends the selected div to back of other div.
If I apply this to blue div and select blue div it should look like below image`

[image]

Basically I'm trying to minic the functionality of `Arrange --> Order --> Send to back` of `Google Presentation`

I did try `z-index` with no success. I can use `background-gradient` with the overlaped part of `blue div transparent` but that will invole some calculations which I want to avoid.

How to acheive this in HTML?
Any help is appreciated.

Note: All `div` elements are placed with `position: absolute`
**Update:** The `red div` lies above the `blue div` as its `z-index` is higher than `blue div`. When `red div` is selected it should look like below (with border highlighted).

[image]

Now if I select the `blue div` a part of it that overlapes with `red div` does not appear (obviously since its `z-index` is lesser) but I want its `border` to appear when I select.it.

Comment: [You mean like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLzX/)?

Comment: You were right to use `z-index`, but you may want to look into how to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=z-index+not+working

Comment: @Mr.Alien I regret for not mentioning the details as required. Now I guess you will understand my question as I added more details. By the way thanks for replying.

Comment: @Shubhmay Please check out the demo 3

Comment: @Vucko I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLzX/6/) but when I click `blue div` I want only its `border` to be `visible` which is overlaped with `red` not entire `blue div`. Please see first image in my question.

Comment: @Shubhmay http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've commented, I guess what you need is this, also, just call a `class` on a `div` which you want to stack up.

[**Final Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/7/)

---

I am not getting your question quiet well, but I assume you want to bring an element above another when it is clicked, than you can do it this way

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/)

Explanation:

What am doing here is, am simply applying `z-index` on the `div` you click using jQuery.

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/2/) (As you updated your question)

---

Using `border` to mark the current selected `div`

```
$(".wrap div").click(function(){
    $('.wrap div').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).css({"z-index":"1", "border":"1px solid #000"});
});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/1/)

Code Reference :

```
$(".wrap div").click(function(){
  $(this).css("z-index","1"); 
});

.wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.wrap div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.wrap div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #f00;
    left: 10px;
}

.wrap div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #0f0;
    left: 80px;
}

<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/5/) When I click green div I want part of overlaped red and border of green div visible as in first image of my question

Comment: @Shubhmay I contributed a final demo, though am still not clear what exactly you are looking for, thats the reason I've kept all the previous demos in my answer as well, if you want border,than simply add border like http://jsfiddle.net/FKDNf/8/

Comment: Can I share Google presentation demo with you? I guess from that you will get clear idea what I actually need.

Comment: @Shubhmay omg, even my final one is not the thing you wanted? *sigh*, instead of that, try to edit and clear out the question, and am sure we will solve

Comment: [check this example](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wStnObHGUNP0EdY7yzvXe99Vu5yzsCiOdzNRb2HsBQY/edit?usp=sharing) you will get clear idea what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Shubhmay isn't that the same thing I provided you?

Comment: @Shubhmay is this what you want? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/FKDNf/9/).

Comment: @Mr_Green You did what I actually wanted. Thanks for solving my problem.